# How to create a new row for the same record after modifying one of the records and updating a new date?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to make it so that when I change a description from my records, the table will automatically add a new record with a new PRODUCTKEY value which contains the same data as the previous records but with the new description. This new record will also update the dates so that the new start date will become the previous end date, and the new end date will become the SYSDATE which is the date in which the record was last modified.

I have merged my tables together but MERGING only changes all the dates and doesn't add a new record. I do not know what to do anymore.

Here's an example:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_DIM
(
    PRODUCTKEY integer NOT NULL,
    PRODUCTID integer,
    PRODUCTDESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    PRODUCTLINEID integer,
    PRODUCTLINENAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_DIM_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCTKEY)
);

ALTER TABLE PRODUCT_DIM
ADD EFF_START_DATE DATE DEFAULT '27-NOV-17';

ALTER TABLE PRODUCT_DIM 
ADD EFF_END_DATE DATE DEFAULT '27-NOV-17';

CREATE SEQUENCE PRODUCT_KEY_SEQ
  MINVALUE 1001
  START WITH 1001
  INCREMENT BY 1
  CACHE 25;


INSERT INTO PRODUCT_DIM
(PRODUCTKEY, PRODUCTID, PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, PRODUCTLINEID, PRODUCTLINENAME)
SELECT PRODUCT_KEY_SEQ.NEXTVAL, nvl(to_char(p.PRODUCTID), 'Undefined'), nvl(to_char(p.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION), 'Undefined'),
nvl(to_char(p.PRODUCTLINEID), 'Undefined'), nvl(to_char(pl.PRODUCTLINENAME), 'Undefined')
FROM PRODUCTLINE_T pl, PRODUCT_T p
WHERE p.PRODUCTLINEID = pl.PRODUCTLINEID;

INSERT INTO PRODUCT_DIM
(PRODUCTKEY, PRODUCTID, PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, PRODUCTLINEID, PRODUCTLINENAME)
VALUES (PRODUCT_KEY_SEQ.NEXTVAL, -99, 'Undefined', -99, 'Undefined');

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT_DIM_HIS
(
    PRODUCTKEY integer NOT NULL,
    PRODUCTID integer,
    PRODUCTDESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    PRODUCTLINEID integer,
    PRODUCTLINENAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    EFF_START_DATE DATE,
    EFF_END_DATE DATE,
    CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_DIM_HIS_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRODUCTKEY)
);


INSERT INTO PRODUCT_DIM_HIS
(PRODUCTKEY, PRODUCTID, PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, PRODUCTLINEID, PRODUCTLINENAME, EFF_START_DATE, EFF_END_DATE)
SELECT PRODUCT_KEY_SEQ.NEXTVAL, nvl(to_char(p.PRODUCTID), 'Undefined'), nvl(to_char(p.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION), 'Undefined'),
nvl(to_char(p.PRODUCTLINEID), 'Undefined'), nvl(to_char(pl.PRODUCTLINENAME), 'Undefined'), 
to_date(o.ORDERDATE), to_date(o.FULFILLMENTDATE)
FROM PRODUCTLINE_T pl, PRODUCT_T p, ORDER_T o, ORDERLINE_T ol
WHERE p.PRODUCTLINEID = pl.PRODUCTLINEID
AND o.ORDERID = ol.ORDERID 
AND ol.PRODUCTID = p.PRODUCTID;

MERGE INTO PRODUCT_DIM_HIS pdh
    USING PRODUCT_DIM pd 
        ON (pdh.PRODUCTID = pd.PRODUCTID) 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET 
        EFF_START_DATE = pd.EFF_START_DATE, 
        EFF_END_DATE = SYSDATE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write procedural code to manage this. There are various options.

One would be to have a stored procedure to wrap the update and insert implementation. This is probably the cleanest approach; it is definitely the approach to take if you need to do this operation in bulk.

Alternatively write a trigger which populates the history table when the source table is changed.

If you have Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.4 or later you could use the built-in Flashback Data Archive feature which maintains history tables transparently. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01011).

Which approach is best depends on how you want to use the history table.